# How to filter objects in parallel using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, filter, parallel-processing, lodash

Currently, I'm calling a database which returns around 1,000 objects.

I filter the objects before publishing it to the user; and as you can imagine, it takes very long to filter 1,000 objects.

My current filter is like this:

```js
if (!isPatient && this._isMounted) {
  this.setState({
    Users: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userSnapData), (k, v) => !v.type || (
      v.type === "Patient" && (_.has(userSnapData[this.state.authUserUID], `Patients`) ? _.has(userSnapData[this.state.authUserUID][`Patients`], k) : true)
    ) ? v : void 0)
  })
}
```

Where `userSnapData` is the data that being retrieved from the database.

```js
/* 
 * this is basically saying, filter the object where the type is "Patient"
 * and it has nested "Patients" object
 */
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userSnapData), (k, v) => !v.type || (
  v.type === "Patient" && (_.has(userSnapData[this.state.authUserUID], `Patients`) ? _.has(userSnapData[this.state.authUserUID][`Patients`], k) : true)
) ? v : void 0)
```

The main issue here is how to filter the data in parallel so that whilst the object has been filtered, I want to straight away show that, rather than waiting for the whole 1000 objects to have been filtered.

Is it possible to use some kind of `Data.map(async element => {...})` Or something similar?

## Update

Suppose I get data like this:

```js
"Users": {
  "w14FKo72BieZwbxwUouTpN7UQm02": {
    "name": "Naseebullah Ahmadi",
    "userType": "Patient",
    "writePermission": false
  },
  "SXMrXfBvexQUXfnVg5WWVwsKjpD2": {
    "name": "Levi Yeager",
    "userType": "Patient",
    "writePermission": false
  },
  "VoxHFgUEIwRFWg7JTKNXSSoFoMV2": {
    "name": "Ernest Kamavuako",
    "userType": "Doctor",
    "writePermission": true
  },
  "hFoWuyxv6Vbt8sEKA87T0720tXV2": {
    "name": "Karla Stanlee",
    "userType": "Doctor",
    "writePermission": true
  }
}
```

I filter them by `userType` and return it as an object, and not an array. This is one of the main issues that after I filter them, I require the data back as an object, and an array of objects.

Comment: javascript is single threaded even if it was async it would still have to wait for items to be filtered

Comment: Why `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userSnapData)`? It looks like you are converting your object to a string and back. This doesn't seem to make too much sense.

Comment: Why are you doing `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` like that? That's probably what your performance bottleneck is.

Comment: Why don't you just decrease the number of records returned by the server perhaps by sending a filter parameter?

Comment: 1000 objects is a very small amount. The bottleneck is somewhere else.

Comment: @JJJ is right 1000 isnt alot

Comment: I agree with you, and honestly, I don't have the answer to that except that it worked like a charm with small data @DanielHilgarth

Comment: @JJJ Hmm i see. This is the only place that I filter it. So I dont think its anywhere else

Comment: Remove the back and forth Json parsing and see how performance is.  If there's an issue after that then maybe consider filtering *before* returning from the server (if possible).

Comment: Would there be a better way of filtering then? @JoeWarner

Comment: Why don't you simply use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the data you're filtering and how you want it filtered? That would help us identify a better way of approaching it.

Comment: Do your filtering on the server. Languages like C# and Scala make it absolutely trivial to filter in parallel leveraging as many threads as possible. In JavaScript you're hopelessly limited to a single thread, making it a poor vehicle for compute-intensive work over a shared data set. The point is, it's CPU bound

Comment: @AluanHaddad You aren't *hopelessly* limited (see: [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)) but you're right, it's better to filter on the server, if possible.

Comment: If you are retrieving data from a database, you should ideally leverage that database's capabilities. SQL databases in particular are well designed for filtering through data sets, and would be much more performant than pulling everything and filtering in js.

Comment: I've updated my question above @MikeC

Comment: @MikeC I need to read up on that, do they have access to shared memory or do they have to serialize everything?

Comment: Cant we use something like Promise.all()? I believe that can be done in parallel

Comment: @Doe that's not parallel, that's interleaved and it's not helpful for CPU bound tasks and it may well slow them down. I do believe that JJJ is correct that 1000 isn't likely enough to matter, but it depends on how complex the objects are and how complex the filters are

Comment: The objects are not that complex. The deepest level of the object is around 2 level. But the objects are very simple and not long in fact. The issue lies with filtering and getting it back as object and not an array of pbjects. @AluanHaddad

Comment: @Doe then your problem is a buggy algorithm, not how it performs. Not only will using promises probably slow it down, it will also obscure your already buggy code that you need to get working correctly before optimizing it.

Comment: @doe depends on how complex your data is and what you're trying to achieve if you're just doing a basic filter then just use .filter if you have some complex conditions and it maybe computationally intensive then looking at algorithms to sort data would be a good idea but i assume the bottle neck is else where not the filtering

Comment: @AluanHaddad For now, serialization is the way to go. Shared memory [will be available in the future.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer)

Comment: @MikeC thanks for the information, I appreciate it. Given that I would strongly favor proper multi-threaded shared memory environments, not JavaScript, for paralyzing collection operations.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated question, just write this

```
const filteredUsers = Object.entries(users)
  .filter(([userId, user]) => user.userType === requiredType)
  .map(([userId, user]) => ({[userId]: user}))
  .reduce(Object.assign, {});
```

If your filtering is truly expensive, and do you wish to paralelize it you can't do so in JavaScript. Promises won't help you at all as they're about interleaved IO, not parallelyzing collection operations. They don't do anything for that except make it slower if anything.

Free compute intensive collection operations, use of language and run time that support multithreaded programming.